# Insert characters when a string changes its case R

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to insert characters in the places were a string change its case. I tried this to insert a '\n' after a fixed number of characters and then a ' ', as I don't figure out how to detect the case change

```
s <-c("FloridaIslandE7", "FloridaIslandE9", "Meta")
gsub('^(.{7})(.{6})(.*)$', '\\1\\\n\\2 \\3', s )

[1] "Florida\nIsland E7" "Florida\nIsland E9" "Meta"
```

This works because the positions are fixed but I would like to know how to do it for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there's a less convoluted `regex` for this, but you could try:

```
gsub('([A-Z][0-9])', ' \\1', gsub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1\n\\2', s))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Florida\nIsland E7" "Florida\nIsland E9" "Meta"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
str_replace_all(s, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "\n")
#[1] "Florida\nIsland\nE7" "Florida\nIsland\nE9" "Meta"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to insert `\n`, try this:

```
gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1\\\n\\2", s)
[1] "Florida\nIsland\nE7" "Florida\nIsland\nE9" "Meta"
```